# Create SP List from a SQL Database

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

How can I create a SharePoint List with a connection to a SQL Database, where i can write my own query to retrieve data from different tables ? (ie. from a star schema)

I checked with 'external content type' in SP Designer, but there i can choose just one table ?!

Or are there any other solutions to populate custom data in a SP List from a database ?

I am working with SP2013 Enterpise

Answer (score 0):

All of the info you need is located here:

How to: Create external content types for SQL Server in SharePoint 2013
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220063.aspx

**Select a table, view, or routine:**

In the Data Source Explorer, expand the database to view the tables, views, and routines that it contains.
Select a table, view, or routine.

Another resource:
http://lightningtools.com/bcs/creating-an-external-content-type-with-sharepoint-designer-2013/